# how to save data of an activity when accidental crash occurs

Tags: android, android-activity, textview

I have a mail application. In my mail text box, I need to type a long text with more than 1000 words. If anything happens and activity crashes, my data gets lost. How do I save the data so that when I re-open my activity after crash, the whole typed mail stays present in the text box without loss?

Comment: You should save the text when the user changes it.

Answer (score 2):

Set a listener to your mail `EditText` and as the user types, save the text in `Database`, or in `SharePreferences`, and at the end when user sends the email or somehow finishes the job (without crash), clear the saved data. But, every time activity opens, check the `Database` whether any texts exist there, if anything exists, load that to your mail `EditText`. So, if activity crashed, you can load last typed data again.

**EDIT**: for getting better performance, do not save each typed character into `Database`. Instead, you can detect each word, and save it, by detecting `white space` characters.

as a guide to [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) and [SQLite Databases](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html), use the links given.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) and [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Example:

```
edittextMail.addTextChangedListener(textwatcher);

private TextWatcher textwatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable aChar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence aChar, int aStart, int aCount, int aAfter) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence aChar, int aStart, int aCount, int aAfter) {
            saveData();
        }
    };

private void saveData() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getSharedPreferences("sharedkey", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor sharedPrefEditor = sharedPref.edit();


    sharedPrefEditor.putString("textsaved", editText.getText().toString());
    sharedPrefEditor.commit();
}


private void retrieveData() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getSharedPreferences("sharedkey", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);


    editText.setText(sharedPref.getString("textsaved", "No string retrieved."));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this method in my apps. Perhaps it could help you with your situation.

In the **onPause()** method

```
@Override

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(0).edit();
        editor.putString("text", txtPostToWall.getText().toString());
        editor.putInt("selection-start", txtPostToWall.getSelectionStart());
        editor.putInt("selection-end", txtPostToWall.getSelectionEnd());
        editor.commit();
    }
```

And then, to retrieve the saved data, in the **onResume()** method

```
@Override

    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();

        SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(0);
        String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);
        if (restoredText != null)   {
            txtPostToWall.setText(restoredText, BufferType.EDITABLE);

            int selectionStart = prefs.getInt("selection-start", -1);
            int selectionEnd = prefs.getInt("selection-end", -1);
            if (selectionStart != -1 && selectionEnd != -1) {
                txtPostToWall.setSelection(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps.